# Extending the editable box to the end of the detailsview table, using ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

I am currently tasked to do a SQL database with web interface. I am using the Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express to develop the prototype. 

My question is, using the detailsview to edit the user information, how do I make the editable text box to be extended to the end of the table? If possible, the text box can extend downwards with excess text wrapped.

The [picture](http://i628.photobucket.com/albums/uu10/edwinckk1977/Temp%20Pictures/Table.jpg) here shows my current output.

**Here is my code...**

```
<%@ Page Title="Display Staff Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="DisplayStaff.aspx.cs" Inherits="ASCBioData.About" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Display Staff Biography
    </h2>
    <p>
        Staff:
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
            InsertMethod="Insert" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
            SelectMethod="GetData" 
            TypeName="ASCBioData.Data.StaffDataTableAdapters.ASCBioDataTableAdapter">
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Education" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="BIO" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Highlights" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
        <asp:DetailsView ID="StaffTable" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
            CellPadding="10" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource2" ForeColor="#333333" 
            GridLines="None" Height="50px" Width="916px">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#8E8064" Wrap="True" />
            <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#D0D0D0" Font-Bold="True" VerticalAlign="Top" 
                Width="70px" />
            <Fields>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
                    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" Visible="False" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Education" HeaderText="Education" 
                    SortExpression="Education" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="BIO" HeaderText="BIO" SortExpression="BIO" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Highlights" HeaderText="Highlights" 
                    SortExpression="Highlights" />
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            </Fields>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <InsertRowStyle Height="300px" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
        </asp:DetailsView>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource2" runat="server" 
            InsertMethod="Insert" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
            SelectMethod="GetDataByID" 
            TypeName="ASCBioData.Data.StaffDataTableAdapters.ASCBioDataTableAdapter" 
            UpdateMethod="UpdateStaffData">
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Education" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="BIO" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Highlights" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="IsID" 
                    PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_ID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Education" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="BIO" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Highlights" Type="String" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

Please advise and thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<asp:TemplateField />` then inside you can use `<asp:TextBox />` and set `TextMode="MultiLine"`. So something like

```
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<%# Eval("Highlights") %>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Highlights") %>'
        TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This is on top of my head so do test the syntax.. but it should give you what you're looking for.